# Determine transformation "kinds" from transformation matrix (reversing)

Tags: opencv, matrix, coordinate-transformation

I'm wondering if I can determine in `OpenCV` the transformation kinds (rotation, translation, shear, ...) just from a given transformation matrix?

Following up on this article: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html

I will get an 2x3 Transformation matrix. E.g.:

```
[ 0.85, 0.20, 0;
 -0.06, 0.37, 253.44]
```

I know that the third "column" stands for the translation. So in this case `x=0`, `y=253.44`

But is there a way of determine if in the first two columns only a rotation or a rotation and a scaling is applied? So what I mean is get the matrix multiplication somehow reversed?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible in general. For example, consider the affine transformation:

```
 cos(theta)  sin(theta)  0
-sin(theta)  cos(theta)  0
```

If `theta = pi`, then this evaluates to

```
-1  0  0
 0 -1  0
```

Is this affine transformation scaling by -1, or rotating by 180 degrees?

Affine transformations *can* indeed be written as a composition of multiple transformations, but as matrix multiplication is not commutative, the order of these compositions matter. And that even goes for translation. The resulting transformation matrix is different if you rotate and then translate than if you translate and rotate, because rotation happens around the (0, 0) location in your image.

In short, there is no unique decomposition. If you know certain constraints, like scaling is uniform, or shearing is uniform, or the scaling is only positive, etc, then you *might* be able to get a unique decomposition. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415854/decompose-affine-transformation-including-shear-in-x-and-y) for the mathematics.